# Why does my NSURLSession dataTask make multiple calls to the server?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I have a NSURLSession dataTask created using the following method:

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *defaultConfigObject = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    NSURLSession *defaultSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration: defaultConfigObject delegate:hvc delegateQueue:    [NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];
NSURLSessionDataTask * dataTask = [defaultSession dataTaskWithURL:url ];
    [dataTask setAccessibilityLabel:@"UserProfiling"];

    [dataTask resume];
```

Here, hvc is another ViewController where I am handling the delegate for this server data task call.

I see that the dataTask is making multiple calls to the server continuously.

Is there a way to ensure that only one call is made?

This has been solved and answered below.

Comment: Have you checked with a log, that the code you posted above isn't being called multiple times?

Comment: Where are the logs present for such server logs?

Comment: I'm not asking about server logs. Just put a log above [dataTask resume] to see if you're calling that method repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

I am answering my own question here.

By mistake, I was writing the above code in another method which was being called repeatedly. It was the Corelocation framework that was continuously updating the user's location.